# How to rotate character to the opposite direction smooth slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Update()
{
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, .05f);
}
```

The problem it's not always rotating by 180. I control the character movement and rotation and at some point i want the character to rotate to the opposite direction no  matter what direction he is facing now.

If Y on the rotation is 120 or 45 or 4 or 23 always rotate to the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you need an `IEnumerator` that maintains the original angle and changes it over time, keep in mind that Point to point changes can never be defined directly in Update or you will have to use a hypothetical variable in Consider the body of the class, which is not recommended.

```cs
public IEnumerator DoRotate(float time)
{
    var newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up) * transform.rotation;

    var baseRotation = transform.rotation;

    var progress = 0f;

    while (progress < 1)
    {
        progress += Time.deltaTime / time;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(baseRotation, newRotation, progress);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

After defining `IEnumerator`, it is enough to start it only once, where it is needed, as below, and the character will rotate at the defined time.

```cs
public void Start() => StartCoroutine(DoRotate(2f)); // rotate over 2 seconds
```

Comment: for some reason i tried to change the time from 3 to something else but it seems that it keep rotating very fast even if the time is set to 3 or 1 or higher the rotations is taking less then a second.  what could be the problem ?

Comment: @SharoSA Sorry, I forgot to save the base rotation before doing coroutine while, Fixed in edited answer.